# Mouseenter when moving and removing elements

Tags: javascript

Run and consider this here snippet.

If we hover the top row ("one") it will turn red like expected. If we then click it, it will be removed according to plan.

However, since the cursor will now be in the second row ("two") I would then expect "mousenter" to fire and make that row red too. But if we keep the mouse still while clicking mousenter does not seem to fire.

Is there a way to force it to fire?

```js
function hideMe (elmnt) {
  elmnt.remove()
  // elmnt.style.display = "none" (is an alternative solution
  // that works, but is not what I need)
}

function iveBeenHovered (elmnt) {
 elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="hideMe(this)" onmouseenter="iveBeenHovered(this)">One</div>
<div onclick="hideMe(this)" onmouseenter="iveBeenHovered(this)">Two</div>
<div onclick="hideMe(this)" onmouseenter="iveBeenHovered(this)">Three</div>
```

Comment: on Firefox Mac the second line immediately becomes red after clicking the first one and not moving

Comment: On Chrome windows works fine too

Comment: Ok interesting. I'm a mac/chrome. Note that as soon as you move the mouse as little as one pixel, mouseenter fires.

Comment: I am actually NOT a mac. I am one one however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nextElementSibling` to find next element and put background before remove.

Check this code:

```js
function hideMe (elmnt) {
  elmnt.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = "red"
  elmnt.remove()
  // elmnt.style.display = "none" (is an alternative solution
  // that works, but is not what I need)
}

function iveBeenHovered (elmnt) {
 elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="hideMe(this)" onmouseenter="iveBeenHovered(this)">One</div>
<div onclick="hideMe(this)" onmouseenter="iveBeenHovered(this)">Two</div>
<div onclick="hideMe(this)" onmouseenter="iveBeenHovered(this)">Three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could force `iveBeenHovered`function on the next element when you click one of them.

```
function hideMe (elmnt) {
  if ( elmnt.nextSibling != null ){
    iveBeenHovered( elmnt.nextSibling );
  }
  elmnt.remove()
}
```

Comment: The OP hasn't tagged their with jQuery which your answer would require

Comment: @j08691 Modified it